# Displaying Two Camera Views in the App

Tags: android, camera

Working on to  display two camera views in my Android Application.
The Rear Camera and External WebCamera. But couldn't get working so far.
Referred all the articles but they don't have a good pointers to flow.

PS: Already checked the USB WebCamera and also Samsung Dual Camera Feature. But my requirement is different.

Update : What I need is a way to take pictures from Rear Camera and USB Camera simultaneously without any lag and store them.

Comment: what is your question....

Comment: I'm afraid you won't get any help on here without showing what you have tried. This "question" is way too broad to get any meaningful feedback.